# How can i get JSON using Soap from ASMX To Listview?

Tags: android, web-services

i modify this code but not working.how can i get json on soap with no param to listview?. my image is JSON Data and i test open website on devices it's work.

```
private class LoadJS extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {
    String resultedData = null;
    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
        SoapObject request = new SoapObject("http://tempuri.org/", "TESTUSERJSON");
        SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);
        envelope.dotNet = true;
        envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);
        HttpTransportSE androidHttpTransport = new HttpTransportSE("http://10.0.2.2/MyService/Service.asmx?WSDL");
        androidHttpTransport.debug = true;
        try {
            androidHttpTransport.call("http://tempuri.org/TESTUSERJSON", envelope);
            SoapPrimitive response = (SoapPrimitive) envelope.getResponse();
            resultedData = response.toString();

        } catch (Exception ex) {
            resultedData = "Error";
        }
        return resultedData;
    }     
}
```

[Json data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xw7Ri.png)

Comment: Did you log the `resultedData` to see if you get the Json in there?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have the result in a String called `resultedData`, you just parse it normally like this:

```
JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(resultedData);
for (int i = 0, i < jsonArray.length(), i++) {
   JSONObject jsonObject = jsonArray.get(i);
   // THIS IS WHERE YOU DO WHAT YOU LIKE WITH EACH OBJECT IN THE ARRAY
   String userId = jsonObject.getString("userId");
   String userPwd = jsonObject.getString("userPwd");
}
```

Comment: Tosk,Log and Debug not work on this class i can't see data , i using on fragment